# UIColor, UIBarButtonItem & MBProgressHUD. Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, mbprogresshud

I have recently updated my Xcode to 7.3 (swift 2.2) and since then my MBProgressHUD isn't working as it did before. Rather than adding the MBProgressHUD statically i used CocoaPods.

I have the pod file below:

[image]

I am now getting the error below when trying to set a duration on the MBProgressHUD and text:

[image]

Also, i have a similar problem with UIColor's and UIBarButtonItem's:

[image]

EDIT:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: in the acknowledgement superclass, check if there exists these methods, label and hide animated

Comment: change label to labelText and hideAnimated to hide. This might work.

Comment: @BhavukJain Thanks that worked!

Comment: Is this to do with the swift 2.2 language?

Comment: @BhavukJain Also, i have a similar problem with UIColor's and UIBarButtonItem's. Do you know anything about this? (See above)

Comment: @BhavukJain Thanks that got rid of some errors. Now on the colours i am getting "Could not infer for type 'BubblegumPink'" & "Could not infer for type 'BubblegumBlue'".

Comment: Better remove ": UIColor" thing. It will automatically cast it as UIColor.

Comment: Thanks I did that and cleaned the project and it now works!